# remove inline style properties and add html attributes using php

Tags: php, css, attributes, addition

1) convert

```
<table style="width: 700px; height: 300px; background-color: #ff0000;" border="0">
```

to

```
<table width="700" height="300" bgcolor="#ff0000" border="0">
```

2) convert

```
<table style="width: 700px; background-color: #ff0000;" border="0">
```

to

```
<table width="700" bgcolor="#ff0000" border="0">
```

I'm using Joomla 1.5.x where in content client can add table or nested tables. Tinymce using inline styles for table dimensions, background properties. But when we try to generate pdf from front end inline styles for table are ignored. Joomla is using TCPDF to generate I've updated the version but same problem. When I've converted the css properties into html attributes, it is generating the table in formated way. So thought to replace all inline styles for table, td, th to html attributes. Tried with many thread from this website but unable to make use of them as I'm poor at regular expressions.

Please any help me in doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use PHP DOM for this.

1) Use DOMElement::getAttribute() to get the value of attribute `style=`

2) Use `$split = explode(";", $style)` to separate those css values

3) With each entry $i of $split, `$attributes = explode(":", $split[$i])`, in get attribute's name and its value.

4) Now you got $attributes holding 2 values: attribute and value of that attribute.

5) Use DOMElement::setAttribute() to add those values of $attributes.

So, put everything into codes:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$atrvalue= $dom->getAttribute("style");

$split = explode(";", $atrvalue);

for ($i=0; $i<=count($split); $i++) {
    $attribute = explode(":", $split[$i]);
    $node = $doc->createElement("table");
    $newnode = $doc->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute($attribute[0], $attribute[1]);
}
```

This way doesn't involve regex :) But you need to modify it in order to fit your context.

Comment: Le: thank you. But my $html doesn't have only table tag, it is html content with p, div, span, b, table tags. Your answer will be helpful only when I've only table.

Comment: Is your question fixed? I think it doesn't matter what tags you're having, you can just put possible tags in array like $arr = array('table', 'a', 'p', 'span') and process using loop :) I can't give you the exact answer when you can actually find it yourself :)